# Adding /etc/environment makes bash fail

Tags: bash, redhat, environment-variables, etc

On RHEL 6.7, I've added the file /etc/environment:

```
JAVA_HOME="/opt/jdk1.8.0_91"
JRE_HOME="{JAVA_HOME}/jre"
M2_HOME="/usr/local/apache-maven"
M2="{M2_HOME}/bin"
PATH="{JAVA_HOME}/bin:{JRE_HOME}/bin:{M2}:{PATH}"
```

Now on login, bash gives the following errors:

```
-bash: id: command not found
-bash: id: command not found
-bash: id: command not found
-bash: uname: command not found
```

Removing or renaming /etc/environment makes the problem go away.

Note: I do not want to use /etc/profile because I want these settings to be available to non-interactive shells.

Answer (score 3):

`/etc/environment` doesn't perform variable expansion. Thus, your `PATH` is now literally `{JAVA_HOME}/bin:{JRE_HOME}/bin:{M2}:{PATH}`, which won't work of course.

If you use `bash` only, you might want to look into setting `$BASH_ENV` in `/etc/environment` like so:

```
BASH_ENV=/etc/non-inter-test
```

where `/etc/non-inter-test` is then read and executed by non-interactive shells (and only those, so you must reference the same file in `/etc/profile` for interactive shells) and might contain what is now in your `/etc/environment`.